# df.groupby(...).apply(...).reset_index() in dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I want to use two Dask DataFrame to process large csv files, and I need to do a groupby(...).apply(...).reset_index() on one DataFrame before joining it with the other:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["x1", "x2", "x2", "x1", "x3", "x2"],
                   'y': ["A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "E"]})
ddfA = dd.from_pandas(dfA, npartitions=2)

gA = ddfA.groupby('x').y.apply(list, meta=('y', 'str')).reset_index()

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["x1", "x2", "x3"],
                   'z': ["U", "V", "W"]})
ddfB = dd.from_pandas(dfB, npartitions=2)


gA.merge(ddfB, how='left', on='x')
```

Unfortunately, I have a keyError : 'x'. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `agg(list)` helps solve the issue.

```py
dfA = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": ["x1", "x2", "x2", "x1", "x3", "x2"], "y": ["A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "E"]}
)
ddfA = dd.from_pandas(dfA, npartitions=2)

gA = ddfA.groupby("x").y.agg(list).reset_index()

dfB = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["x1", "x2", "x3"], "z": ["U", "V", "W"]})
ddfB = dd.from_pandas(dfB, npartitions=2)

print(gA.merge(ddfB, on="x", how="left").compute())

    x          y  z
0  x1     [A, B]  U
1  x2  [B, C, E]  V
2  x3        [D]  W
```

If one of the DataFrames is smaller than the other, you may want to look into a broadcast join cause that'll be a lot more performant.

Comment: What if I need to use a custom function that works on multiple columns of the dataframe?
I'm facing an issue where I actually need to `groupby().apply()` and then use the new column generated by `reset_index`. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @ViníciusSilva - feel free to create a new question if you need help with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure what is your desired output, but if you change the order of the line you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["x1", "x2", "x2", "x1", "x3", "x2"],
                   'y': ["A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "E"]})

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["x1", "x2", "x3"],
                   'z': ["U", "V", "W"]})


gA = dfA.merge(dfB, how='left', on='x')
gA = dd.from_pandas(gA, npartitions=2)
gA


    x   y   z
npartitions=2           
0   object  object  object
3   ... ... ...
5   ... ... ...
```

Comment: Thant you for the answer. I have large files that's why I want to use Dask DataFrame instead of Pandas for dfA and dfB.